# Angular material md-tab scrolling content

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to set a scrollable content with `overflow-y: scroll` css style in a md-tab but it's not working The scrollbar is displayed but it's not activated

I enabled it with fixing a height but I want it to fit the content height dynamically

how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: I have the same issue !

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are trying to keep the tab header out of the scrollable area and make the tab content scrollable only. If that's the case you can set height of tab content with `vh`. That will keep the tab labels in view and make the height dynamic and content scrollable.

css:

```
>>> .mat-tab-body-content {
    height: 90vh !important;
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/e3QAYZMa92zbmDcALN3v?p=preview)

If this is not what you are looking for, please explain the question little bit further or add some code.