# Angular 15 Material Tab Control: Is it possible to auto scroll content only?

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material, tabs, scrollbar

With Angular Material 15, is it possible to keep the tab control **tabs** in view when the **content** overflows and apply scrollbars to the content only?

View on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-15-material-tab-control)

I've previously rejected the use of [Material Tab Control](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) as it didn't work well with [Flex Layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout). As @angular/flex-layout is now deprecated, I've given this another go using [CSS Flexbox](https://blog.angular.io/modern-css-in-angular-layouts-4a259dca9127). However, I can't work out how to add scrollbars to the content only when the content overflows.

The issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365843/how-to-scroll-only-the-content-of-a-mat-tab) but the Stackblitz links are no longer working and the solution proposed by [liviu-nita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10911470/liviu-nita) seems like a less than ideal work-around.

[Dynamic height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722183/angular-material-tab-height) seems to be irrelevant to the issue, and I've not been able to adapt the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085849/angular-material-md-tab-scrolling-content).

Demo of the issue on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-15-material-tab-control)

How the control is rendered:

[image]